# Textbox scroll to line doesnt work when changing text

Tags: wpf, scroll, textbox

So I have a text box, and when the user scrolls passed a certain point, it loads new text in the text box, and then it should scroll to the line I tell it to scroll to. Here is the code:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string fileName;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";

            fileName = ofd.FileName;
            TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
        }
    }

    private bool ignoreScroll = false;

    private int lineScroll = 0;

    private bool scrollToLine = false;

    int firstChange = 500;
    int i = 0;
    private void TextBox1_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ignoreScroll)
        {
            ignoreScroll = false;
            return;
        }


            if (TextBox1.GetFirstVisibleLineIndex() > firstChange)
            {

                        ignoreScroll = true;
                      //  TextBox1.Text = "";
                        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName) ;
                        TextBox1.ScrollToLine(firstChange);
                        firstChange += 500;
                        TextBox1.Focus();
                        i++;
            }



    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestLoadAndScroll.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Background="Black">
    <TextBox Name="TextBox1" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="TextBox1_ScrollChanged"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="213" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="406"/>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" Content="Open" Height="30" Width="100" />
</Grid>
```

This works when the text is not changing. Even though I am resetting the text in the textbox, I am setting it to its previous contents, and the scroll to line function works, but if I change the line:

```
TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName) ;
```

to

```
TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName) + i;
```

Now the text actually changes every time I load it, and the scroll to line function call doesn't get executed and textbox stays at the top of the document.

Why does changing the text make the call to scroll to line not work? Is there  a way to make this work?